# How do you deploy an edit/add custom form to Sharepoint 2010 without modifying views or data on target server?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, deployment, custom-form

I have a custom content type and list on a SharePoint 2010 server.  The edit/add forms are custom, built in SharePoint Designer.  I want to modify the layout of the forms including a new field, but the target server does not and will not have SharePoint Designer.  In addition, current list data and views already exists on the target server.  Is there a way to customize these forms on the target server without destroying the current data and all the views the user already added?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to take a different approach, since the user of the application will never have SharePoint Designer, I have decided to create a custom solution in Visual Studio using an application page and a combination of server sire SP Object Model and SPServices.  If anyone is interested in more details, let me know.  Still in the middle of developing/modifying, but it is working, gives me more flexability in future deployments.